# How to display a new taxonomy term on a select box using Webform?

Tags: webforms

I am using Drupal 7. I have Webform and Webform Term Options installed. I have a taxonomy list of terms called "Training Events". Under "Load a Pre-Built Options List" I select the Training Events list, and save. I view the webform and the list of taxonomy terms is there on the select list. However, if I go to Structure -> Taxonomy -> List terms -> Add term and add a new term, that new term does not appear on the webform. Why won't it appear and do I make it appear?

Answer (score 0):

The error was I was adding a new vocabulary, not a new taxonomy term to the existing vocabulary.